# Bluetooth RFCOMM channel - Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've managed to set up a bluetooth server by adapting the Bluetooth chat example code provided with the Android SDK. I have one question regarding how to find the channel of the created bluetoothserversocket. My Debugger says following, when I start the server:

[image]

Can I for sure say that the RFCOMM channel is `64`? By looking at the second line from logcat? I need this specific channel because I need to make a config file for my non-android bluetooth device, which will connect and send me some files.

Answer (score 1):

the channel should be exchanged via SDP

Comment: so if I do a sdptool browse under linux, the channel should appear?